# Orientation image image after use Front or Back camera

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

i use camera in my app for capture image , when switch to the front camera, the picture is mirrorrd . i use this code for take picture (rotate and compensate the mirror)
with this code Back camera is OK (without mirror and rotate)! 
but Front camera result be similar this picture :

[image]

this method for get Front camera id :
(i use CameraInfo to get Front camera id and send id to result activity)

```
    public int getFrontFacingCameraId() {
        int numCameras = getNumberOfCameras();
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int cameraId = 0; cameraId < numCameras; cameraId++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                return cameraId;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

this code for rotation : (use matrix)

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(angle);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

and this code use in activity result :

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), IMG_URI);
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                        int degrees = 0;
                        switch (rotation) {
                            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                                degrees = 90;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                                degrees = 180;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                                degrees = 270;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                                degrees = 360;
                                break;
                        }
                        int displayOrientation;
                        if (cameraInfo.facing == getFrontFacingCameraId()) {
                            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                            displayOrientation = (360 - displayOrientation) % 360;
                        } else {
                            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                        }
                        USER_CIRCLE_PHOTO.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotateImage(thumbnail, displayOrientation), 480, 800, false));
                        getContentResolver().delete(IMG_URI, null, null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        displayToast(this, "خطای گرفتن عکس:" + "\n" + e.toString());
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix the problem
Thank you

and when change to this :

```
case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                                degrees = 0;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                                degrees = 90;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                                degrees = 180;
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                                degrees = 270;
                                break;
```

result :
[image]

[image]

back and for camera not OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/***Inside your Picture Taken Call back try to change**/

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback()
{

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{

    pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    if (pictureFile == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        path = pictureFile.getPath();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        if (pictureFile.exists())
        {

            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());


            if(cameraId == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            {
                imageRotation(largeIcon);



            }
            else
            {

                 rotateFrontImage(largeIcon);



            }






        }



        /* * Make the callback to the calling activity to handle picture
         * clicked*/

        mCallback.imageClicked(pictureFile);


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

};

/***********************************************/

public Bitmap rotateFrontImage(Bitmap source)
{

Bitmap rImg;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{

    Bitmap imgBitmap = source;

    ExifInterface ei = null;
    try
    {

        ei = new ExifInterface(path );

        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);


        switch(orientation)
        {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                imgBitmap = rotateImage(source, 90);


                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                imgBitmap = rotateImage(source, 180);


                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                imgBitmap = rotateImage(source, 270);


                break;


        }

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

                   }

    Matrix rotateRight = new Matrix();
    rotateRight.preRotate(270);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13 &&  cameraId == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
    {

        float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        //rotateRight = new Matrix();
        Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
        matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

        rotateRight.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

        Log.i(TAG, "rotateFrontImage if mirrorY: "+mirrorY);
        Log.i(TAG, "rotateFrontImage if matrixMirrorY: " + matrixMirrorY);


    }

    rotateRight.preRotate(90);

     rImg= Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 0, 0, imgBitmap.getWidth(), imgBitmap.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);


}

else
{



    Matrix rotateRight = new Matrix();
    rotateRight.preRotate(270);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13 &&  cameraId == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
    {


        float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        rotateRight = new Matrix();
        Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
        matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

        rotateRight.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

        Log.i(TAG, "rotateFrontImage else mirrorY: "+mirrorY);
        Log.i(TAG,"rotateFrontImage else matrixMirrorY: "+matrixMirrorY);

        rotateRight.preRotate(270);

    }

    rImg= Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);


}

 return rImg;
 }
```